# How to setup shared clipboard between host and guest, guest in virtualbox running headless by vagrant

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, clipboard

I'm on windows. I use vagrant, virtual box to setup the ubuntu vm, running headless.

Now I'm using kitty ssh into the vm, I can copy from the host and do paste in the guest by right clicking the mouse. or by `shift + insert`.

But I can't figure out how to copy from guest and paste into host. especially when I want to copy from the vim editor by press "yy", I don't know where the text has gone after I do copy. Even if I just want to do copy paste all in guest os, I don't know how to do that!!

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do copy from the guest, it didn't work is due to that in vim, I'm selecting those text using vim's selection mode, that won't work.  you need to use the mouse to highlight the text you want to copy and press `ctrl + insert`, then those texts will be in the clipboard